# Moodle Configuration error in mysql version update

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, moodle

I am configuring moodle 2.8.1 version.
while configuring it loads a page where Server Checks are validated.

I have sorted all the errors and now it is displaying only one server check error which is

```
mysql (5.0.81-community-nt)
version 5.5.31 is required and you are running 5.0.81
```

where I have installed newer version of PhpMyAdmin which is:
[image]

But I don't understand why moodle gives me error like:
[image]

It says I am running mysql version 5.0.x
but I have installed newer version of mysql which is 5.6.x

plz anyone help me out through this.

Thank you

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Is there any chance you're running another older installation of mysql server?

Comment: No, I am using Windows 7, and I just installed fresh windows, and then downloaded the latest wamp version and installed it..

Answer (score 5):

Go to htdocs and find moodle "config.php" then on $CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli'; change into $CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';

It means that you should change your dbtype to mariadb instead off mysqli

Comment: Hey Hi, it is necessary to change the type ? does it affect to any database thing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Update PHP to 5.6.6, might solve your problem.
URL: http://php.net/downloads.php