Wrong $CFG->dbtype. You need to change it in your config.php file from 'mysqli' to 'mariadb'
I am trying to install Moodle the last version of Moodle 4.4.2, and everything except the database keeps telling me that I should change mysqli to MariaDB in the config.php file. I have MySQL installed with the XAMPP on my PC and I don't have MariaDB. I don't want to use it and I have no idea why it keeps showing me this error!

I tried to do as the msg says and changed mysqli to MariaDB and installed MariaDB but it didn't work maybe due to a configuration problem. Please don't tell me to switch to MariaDB I want to keep using MySQL for the project.

Well, that doesn't make any sense. This message is stupid. mysqli is a PHP extension. MariaDB is a RDBMS. That's like saying you need to change your dog for oranges. Contact the developers of this application and report this issue to them.

XAMPP does come with MariaDB, which is a fork (variant) of MySQL. If you look at the information column, it says mysql (10.4.32-MariaDB). Make sure you're changing the right config file

mysqli is an interface type, not a database type. Try mysql instead.

@Wiimm I checked Moodle source code, mysql is aliased to mysqli in their configuration. So it shouldn't matter what they write.

Isn't that just the setting in the config-file? A quick search revealed this posting where that was the case: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=406916#p1665107 Change it and see if it works.

I closed it as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500894/moodle-configuration-error-in-mysql-version-update but OP claims they tried changing that already and it didn't solve the problem.

I think using mysqli was a typo. Clearly this option describes a database, not interface

I finally fixed the problem, first I changed mysqli to mariadb in config.php then I went to mysqli_native_moodle_database.php and affected the string "10.6.7" to the variable $serverversion and now it's working fine.
And of course, I downloaded MariaDB 10.6.7 before.
